# Turning on XML syntax highlighting in vim for a non-XML file

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I'm using vim to browse through some log files (the file extension is `.log`) which contain a lot of XML.

How can I turn on XML syntax highlighting after opening the file?  Of course, I don't actually want to associate XML syntax highlighting with *all* log files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The command you want is "`:setfiletype`". For example:

```
:setf xml
```

See "`:help :setfiletype`".

Comment: Beautiful, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can place this in your ~/.vimrc file as well

```
au BufNewFile, BufRead *.extension_name set filetype=xml
```

Replace **extension_name** with the extension you want, reopen vim, and you will see xml syntax highlight.

Comment: This didn't work for me, [this answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5202/5280) did work: `autocmd BufEnter *.extension_name :setlocal filetype=xml`

Comment: It should be noted that this will cause *all* `.extension_name` files to be treated as the given filetype, which is behavior specifically mentioned as *not* wanted in the question. Still, potentially useful to others, so no downvote from me.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [@RubyFanatic answer](https://superuser.com/a/540780/493903), what worked for me was (in `vim`'s command mode):

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.extension_name setf xml
```